# Ember 1.13 - Recompute helper when global variable change

Tags: ember.js

I got a "get-text" helper which translate my static fields depending on a config variable : ENV.LOCALE.

The thing is, I'd like to recompute my if my ENV.LOCALE gets modified. I tried several things from sending events to Ember.observer, without much success.

```
// controllers/application.js
locale: function() {
    var locale = this.get('isFrench') === true ? 'fr' : 'en';
    ENV.LOCALE = locale;

    return locale;
}.property('isFrench'),    


//helpers/get-text.js
import Ember from 'ember';
import ENV from '../config/environment';

export default Ember.Helper ( function(key, locale) {
    var lang = {
        save: {
            'fr': 'Enregistrer',
            'en': 'Save',
        },
    }
    return new Ember.Handlebars.SafeString(lang[key][ENV.LOCALE]);
});
```

Bottom line, how can I recompute my helper when a global property changes?

Comment: Do you expect your config/environment ENV to be updated on your production server while it is running? That can't happen. Even during development, config/environment changes generally require a restart of the ember server anyway. Maybe you want to put a locale in some ED model and persist it for a user?

Comment: @Gaurav That was another question I was wasking myself, if it was "wrong" for me to change an ENV (the page will load and set depending on a meta tag the ENV.LOCALE). However once it's loaded I want to be able to have access to it globally. Let's put the fact that it's in ENV aside, is it possible to recompute a global property?

Comment: I suppose. But how would you test it? You can't change the property without restarting the server.

Comment: In the snippet I showed I actually show an example of how it do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After digging threw the documentation, [I found this chapter about dependency injection](http://guides.emberjs.com/v1.13.0/understanding-ember/dependency-injection-and-service-lookup/). This combined with [the API documentation on Ember.Helper](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Helper.html#method_recompute) I came up with the following solution :

1st I created a service "locale-manager"

```
// services/locale-manager.js
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Service.extend({
    isFrench: true,
    locale: function() {
        var locale = this.get('isFrench') === true ? 'fr' : 'en';
        return locale;
    }.property('isFrench'),    
});
```

Then I inject my service into my helper and recompute it everytime time the property of locale is changed.

```
// helpers/get-text.js
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Helper.extend({
    localeManager: Ember.inject.service(),
    onLocaleChange: Ember.observer('localeManager.locale', function() {
        this.recompute();
    }),
    compute(params) {
        var key = params[0];

        var lang = {
            enregistrer: {
                    'fr': 'Enregistrer',
                    'en': 'Save',
            },

        var locale = this.get('localeManager.locale');
        return new Ember.Handlebars.SafeString(lang[key][locale]);
    }
});
```